# Match last slash if there are at least nth occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex, quantifiers

I need to replace the last slash if there are 3 or more occurrences. If we've a path like this `"/foo/bar/"`, it should become `"/foo/bar"`. But a path like `"/foo/"` should not be touched.

I tried it with an escaped slash (`\/`) and a quantifier (`{3,}`):

```
/\/{3,}$/
```

However, this regular expression matches only *slashes* that are directly after another: `"/foo/bar///"`

Any ideas how I can solve this problem? Maybe with a *positive/negative `lookahead`*?

http://www.regexr.com/393pm

To visualize:

```
"/foo/"         => "/foo/"
"/foo/bar/"     => "/foo/bar"
"/foo/bar/baz/" => "/foo/bar/baz"
```

Thanks to [Fede](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560013/1250044), [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560231/1250044) & [Amal Murali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24559728/1250044)! Since performance matters, @Fede is the winner: http://jsperf.com/match-last-slash-if-there-are-at-least-nth-occurrences

Comment: What would be the output for this `/foo/bar/baz/` string?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `/foo/ => /foo/` but `/foo/bar/ => /foo/bar` and `/foo/bar/baz/ => /foo/bar/baz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\/.*?\/.*(\/)
```

Here you have working example:

http://regex101.com/r/xT3pN1/2

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mkFmj-0FeuDkihbs)

If you want to keep it with content except the last slash, you can use this regex and reference the first group as `\1` :

```
(\/.*?\/.*)(\/)
```

Check the working example with substitution:

http://regex101.com/r/xT3pN1/3

Comment: Great! However, the same problem as with @AmalMurali solution. Replace/match the whole path instead of just the last slash: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qt89S/1/

Comment: @AvinashRaj not sure if OP would want that. He said "I need to replace the last slash if there are 3 or more occurrences".

Comment: @yckart, that's easy to solve, check the updated answer.

Comment: You won the performance test: http://jsperf.com/match-last-slash-if-there-are-at-least-nth-occurrences :)

Comment: @yckart lol, excellent site. Btw, you can improve it a little by removing the 2nd group `(\/)` since you use the 1st.

Comment: @yckart I've tested it without the 2nd group and it increased to 10,208,383 operations by second

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex with a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.*(?:.*?\/){3,})(.*)\/$/m
```

Explanation:

```
^          # Assert position at the beginning of the line
(?=        # Positive lookahead: if followed by
  .*       # Match any number of characters
  (?:      # Begin non-capturing group
    .*?\/  # Match any number of characters followed by a '/'
  )        # End of group
  {3,}     # Repeat the group 3 or more times
)          # End of lookahead
(.*)       # Match (and capture) any number of characters
\/         # Match a literal backslash
$          # Assert position at the end of the line
```

And then replace it with `\1`.

[**Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eO3uA2/2)

Comment: Looks good so far, problem is that I don't get it to replace just the slash: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qt89S/ It just replaces the whole path...

Comment: @yckart: Okay, I misread the question. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
^((?=\/.*?\/.*?\/).*?)([\/]+)$
```

REplace all with the first captured group.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xT3pN1/5)

Comment: Nope, sorry... http://fiddle.jshell.net/qt89S/2/ however, @Fede solution works great :) Thanks for your time! :-*

Comment: try this `^((?=\/.*?\/.*?\/).*?)([\/]+)$`. Replace all with the first captured group.

Comment: How is this different from Fede's answer except that this one uses positive lookahead instead of explicitly matching the string?

Comment: @AmalMurali fede's won't work if the last contains more than one `/`. And i didn't see his update.